# PageSpeed Insights : Load css files after the closing </html>

Tags: html, css, optimization

[Google Page insight](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) tells us to optimize CSS file like this :

> Vous pouvez alors incorporer le code CSS essentiel comme ceci :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .blue{color:blue;}
    </style>
    </head>
  <body>
    <div class="blue">
      Hello, world!
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="small.css">
```

source : https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery

[image]

The French link is https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery?hl=fr

I’ve never seen such a thing : Integrate css files after the closing `</html>` tag.

I’t’s not only in the documentation. It also modify the result of PageSpeed Insights score. I have 100% if i insert css file at the end.

Is it valid HTML ?

Comment: Can you paste the lines where it tells you put the css after the closing html tag?

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Asking for opinions is off-topic.

Comment: I can't see any text suggesting putting stylesheet-includes after the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: @Huangism I can paste the line but it is in french. I can’t access Google Page insight in English (i’ve tried from Google USA but it is still French for me). Look at the code i paste ans the source.

Comment: @Alex Look at the link or the source code i pasted from Google developers doc. they suggest to insert the css line after the closing tag.

Comment: @SébastienGicquel I was unable to find the part where they suggest putting the link tag outside of the html document

Comment: @SébastienGicquel `they suggest to insert the css line after the closing tag.` they also differentiate between critical and non critical content

Comment: @Huangism i've edited the link. It's now in english.

Comment: I read something like this not to long ago. It is stated that the `ESSENTIAL CSS` should be inline, the rest can be loaded later. This has to do with the fact that a css file loads things from elements that arent needed on such page. I, myself, am not a big fan of this, since seeking css in html can be a pain in the ass, and you do it for what, a few miliseconds quicker (stated that we talk about a single easy website with a few 100 lines of css). You can better stick to async loading javascript to increase speed.

Comment: @Huangism The content is different in english. Look at the french link and search "Vous pouvez alors incorporer le code CSS essentiel comme ceci :"

Comment: @SébastienGicquel there isn't a french link on your post

Comment: Is this https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery?hl=fr the french link?

Comment: @Huangism I've posted a screen shot. I don't know why you can't see it. I guess as i am in France, i can see the french link which is different from the english one.

Comment: @SébastienGicquel I have already added the french link to your question which has the code you referred to. I think google is playing a joke on the french. It is not valid to put the link outside of the html tag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your question, it is NOT valid to put the `link` tag outside of the `html` tag

Use https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options and see for yourself. Just paste the code in

> Line 11, Column 40: Stray start tag link.

Then you get

> Line 11, Column 40: Cannot recover after last error. Any further errors will be ignored.

I don't know why that recommendation is even there but it should be removed. Maybe google is just playing a joke on the french? Maybe the page have not been updated. You can probably contact them and ask why if you really want but I would not do this on any of my pages

Comment: To add to your answer, `<link>` tags can be added only to the `<head>` element, without the `itemprop` attribute.

Comment: It's more accurate to say that it's not valid `HTML 4.01` or `XHTML 1.0`.

Comment: @Ezra it's not valid with html5 either

Comment: It's not only the French version, see https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery?hl=en where the code is different but the advise is the same...